# npm cannot find npm-cli module after yosemite upgrade

Tags: node.js, module, path, npm, osx-yosemite

When trying to run `npm` after I updated OS X to yosemite I receive this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

My guess is it has something to do with PATHs but I am not well learned in this area. Please ask if you need anymore info.  Thanks.

### Edit

So the path it is looking for the `npm_cli` module is pretty wacky `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node_modules/npm/bin`

The path that `npm_cli.js` is located at is:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin`

So there's the issue but I still don't actually know how to fix it.

### Edit 2

Here are the relevant entries in my `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
```

Comment: Have you updated Xcode commandline tools after Yosemite upgrade ?

Comment: Yes, just double checked, everything is up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to add `/usr/local/bin` to my `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably it would be simplest to remove and reinstall node and npm.  Is there some reason you can't do that?

Is it possible you have run `npm update -g`?  That can screw things up, leading to a need to reinstall.

If you just want to try reinstalling `npm`, and you have a working `node`, use this script:

curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

Se https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#if-your-npm-is-broken

Comment: I can definitely reinstall node and npm.  I'll give it a try when I get home tonight.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried the above, and ended up at "can't find module ... read-package-json.js"

Answer (score 0):

Run a command to install cli -

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```